# What is the term for pairs of words with converse meanings such as (gave<>got) and (bought<>sold)?

Tags: terminology, english, antonymy

I'm seriously struggling to identify a name for the relationship between such words.
They are transactional terms,of which there are two parts.
They may even show tense.

John *gave* me an apple.
I *got* an apple from John.
I was *given* an apple by John.

I could *buy* it from you.
You could *sell* it too me.
John *sold* it to me.
I *bought* it from john.

I would have thought it was an antonym, but searching for "gave" didn't show me "got".
Is there a special name for such opposing pairs?

Comment: I would say they have the same semantic representation. They are simply lexicalized differently.

Comment: In other words, they are paraphrases.

Comment: The structures are paraphrases, yes, they convey the same meaning.  But I'm looking specifically at the verbs (got/gave, buy/sell, bought/sold etc.).  Is there a special label/classification for words that convey semantic similarity but from opposing sides of a transaction?  The only ones I can think of are verbs and require two participants.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is `conversives`.

Comment: It's a **whole** lot more complicated than _antonym_ or any single term can emcompass. You're dealing with several nested frames here -- `Transfer`, `Barter`, and `Commercial Transaction` -- and each one licenses terms in several different kinds of opposition. The basic frames and details are discussed [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf) and [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf), in different contexts.

Comment: If they rearrange the surface cases to make a particular role the subject, does that make them voice suppletives?

Comment: *Antonym* turns out to have a broader meaning than you expect when you delve in like this. At this level it's maybe not useful to think of it as a technical term. You're looking for very specific types of pairs. But in fact it may turn out that each pair is specific and there's not an exact alignment between them all. For instance *got* is colloquial and has many senses. The more straightforward pair for *gave* would be *received*. In another way they mean the same thing, just from a different point of view, and most people wouldn't want to use *antonym* for a pair where both are the same ...

Answer (score 2):

We are looking at pairs like ‘buy’ ^ ‘sell’; ‘take’ ^ ‘give’; ‘come’ ^ ‘go’. I am not sure that there is name for this, but we are dealing with pairs of verbs with the same fundamental semantic content but opposite directionality. ‘Come’ means to move toward the speaker, ‘go’ means to move away from the speaker; ‘buy’ means to transfer an object into the possession of the speaker; ‘sell’ means to transfer it from the speaker to another person. In English we  use two etymologically distinct words for ‘buy’ and ‘sell’, but German uses ‘kaufen’ and ‘verkaufen’, that is: ‘sell’ is ‘buy’ with a directional prefix. Compare English 'import' vs. 'export'. You will find the same sort of thing frequently in Russian.