# What is the semantic relationship of the words 'ask' and 'tell'?

Tags: semantics

I'm not quite sure which of these semantic relationships it would be: Synonymy, Hyponymy, Hypernymy, and Antonymy. Or would there be no semantic relationship between these words?

Comment: They're both speech act verbs, but that's a large class and the relationship between this particular pair of verbs in the set is unique and, as far as I know, has no special Greek name.

Comment: Related question with a similar semantic relation: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25949/verb-pairs-similar-to-buy-and-sell

Answer (score 3):

I think you can call them *cohyponyms* of words like *speak*, *say*, etc. That is, they are both hyponyms of the same word.

Answer (score 0):

The way they are presented here, you assume they are antonyms in a given context, but you are aware that's not always true. Strictly speaking, you cannot take primary verbs (as opposed to verbs derived from nouns) out of context and assign them tense, aspect, semantic relation, just as you cannot take *man* and assign a unique Position of Sentence (PoS) without corresponding sentence.

Proof: I would always prefer *answer* or *respond*, being a second language learner though, and I tend to understand *tell* as a synonym of *say* (or at least a close hyponym, as *?say me* is not synonym, but *say!* is). But that's off-topic here, because it depends on language specific context. The proof will be complete once the question is closed. And my answer can't be denied by being accepted. This is proof by contradiction. Q.e.d.