# Is there a word for a pair of verbs that mean the same thing but with subject and object swapped?

Tags: terminology, verbs, passive

In logic, you can say:

```
(A and B) --> A           / 'A and B' implies 'A' (as the 'B' is just discarded)
```

Computer programmers working from a specification to an implementation, sometimes talk about "refinement", which is the same relationship, but written in the opposite direction:

```
A <-- (A and B)          / 'A' refines to 'A and B'
```

But you could also state that idea like this:

```
(A and B) --> A          / 'A and B' refines 'A'  (by adding the 'B' constraint)
```

So in this context, the verbs 'imply' and 'refine' are interchangeable, even though they are... not opposites, but... _____ *(I don't know what word to use, hence this question!)*

I'm having a hard time thinking of any other examples in English where one verb (without any prepositions) means the same thing as the passive form of another verb.

Near misses:

- "You tell me, so I hear you." (but these aren't actually same relationship, just two phenomena that happen to coincide. either one could happen without the other).
- "I met you, so you met me." (but this is only one verb)

Are there other examples of this in English? Are there natural languages where something like this occurs? And (my main question): **what would you call the relationship between these two words?**

Comment: Since it seems that you are not just interested in [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice), you may want to look at this question, its answers, and the questions linked to it: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/25949/9781

Comment: The only clear examples I can think of are 'precede' and 'follow'. Experiencer verbs (e.g., 'like' and 'please') come pretty close, but they're not quite synonymous.

Comment: Reciprocal?  (That's how I describe the difference between *compose* and *comprise*.)